# User Role at Wordpress registration in Theme My Login

Tags: wordpress, user-registration

i'm using "Theme My Login" for registration.
want to add a radio button field in register page.
i want user to register either role-1 or role-2 via use of radio button.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Some code?

Comment: yes, added check box to register-form.php but the given valus are not updated in the DB.

Answer (score 4):

No Plugin is required for this you can easily do with below function in your theme-my-login-custom.php

suppose your default user role is subscribe.

```
function tml_new_user_registered( $user_id ) 
{

$u = new WP_User(  $user_id );

if($_REQUEST['radio_button_name']=='value1'){

    // Remove role which is your default 
    $u->remove_role( 'subscriber' );//remove default role

    // Add role
    $u->add_role( 'role1' );
}else
{
    // Remove role
    $u->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

    // Add role
    $u->add_role( 'role2' );

}
}
add_action( 'tml_new_user_registered', 'tml_new_user_registered' );
```

Answer (score -1):

accomplished this by the use of this plugin.

[WP Roles at Registration](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-roles-at-registration/)